# Is there a way to view relationships in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: database, oracle

I want to find which tables are related to a specific table. I can see all the foreign key constraints easily enough, but what about table for which the table I am looking at is the primary key table and the other table is the referenced table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not clear if you're looking for a GUI solution, but you can query the information from the dictionary by:

```
select table_name from user_constraints
where r_constraint_name in
  (select constraint_name 
     from user_constraints
     where constraint_type in ('P','U')
     and table_name = upper('&tableOfInterest')
  )
```

Comment: I was hoping for a GUI type option so that I can just click a button and it will list them. BUT I can make do with this if no one else comes along. Thanks

Comment: There is a product, PL/SQL Developer by Allround Automations that includes this in their GUI interface - they have both  "foreign keys" and "foreign key references" branches in their navigation tree for a table node.  Disadvantages - not free, native to Windows (but will run in Linux under Wine).

Comment: You could also replace `user_constraints` with `all_constraints` to check for relationships.

Answer (score 19):

Steps in SQL Developer

- go to `View` > `Data Modeler` > `Browser` to open up the `Browser` view/tab.
- (`Browser` view/tab*) right click on `Relational Models` and select `New Relational Model` which opens up a new window.

This should create a new blank diagram which one can drag and drop tables from the `Connections` view into the diagram.

Comment: Also, if you click a table, and select "Model", the SQL Developer will generate the part of the (whole) model which is related to this table.

Comment: wow, all that effort to click just on the "Model tab" when opening a table ^^

Comment: This doesn't show the relations between tables. It shows the tables / views, but doesn't show me the references which I can see on the `Dependencies` tab for a specific view / table

Answer (score 2):

See Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html

Comment: I was scared someone would say this. Something extra to install and get working. Is there nothing standard? Also, from what I read, it will only give you an EDR from the tables you select. The problem is that I don't which tables might be referencing the table I am looking at and that is what I want to know.

Comment: I know thanks. I am just trying to clarify what I am looking for. Sorry if I gave you the wrong impression. I am just reluctant for a built-in feature. Was hoping that there was one. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: @tuinstoel i am getting page not found, that is probably expected bc it has been 7 years. any chance to update the link?

Comment: @RamiShareef Try this url: https://web.archive.org/web/20081202130146/http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/files/Modeling.html ,you may also find more helpful answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580529/how-to-generate-an-entity-relationship-er-diagram-using-oracle-sql-developer).