# How to generate data model diagram from Oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, datamodel

I want to generate a data model diagram from an existing oracle database.

I've tried to use SQL Developer 3.2.20.09 and followed the steps in another **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580529/how-to-generate-e-r-diagram-using-oracle-sql-developer)** and the **[demonstration](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/sqldev/ImportDataModel/importdatamodel_viewlet_swf.html)** of oracle.

But I didn't succeed. It's a little strange because I can see **all the other types of objects except tables.**

Here is **my steps:**
File -> Data Modeler -> Import -> Data Dictionary -> current database connection -> Next -> Current Schema -> Next

[image: there is no tables displayed]

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I think it's a specific problem in my database. **I can't figure it out with SQL Developer.
Finally, I've used TOAD Data Modeler to generate E/R diagram.**

Comment: you have the answer for sql developer ?

Comment: I didn't find the answer on internet too. Why do you refuse if you 'had' the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are not solutions proposed by others, I'll mark my "solution" as answer.

I think it's a specific problem in my database.

I can't figure it out with SQL Developer. Finally, I've used TOAD Data Modeler to generate E/R diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we're running to get a list of tables in version 4.1 of SQL Developer Data Modeler:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_TYPE_OWNER
FROM dba_all_tables a
WHERE IOT_NAME IS NULL
AND (IOT_TYPE  IS NULL
OR IOT_TYPE     = 'IOT')
AND NESTED      ='NO'
AND a.OWNER     =?
AND SECONDARY   ='N'
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM dba_queue_tables c
  WHERE OWNER       =?
  AND c.QUEUE_TABLE = a.TABLE_NAME
  )
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Does your connection have access to the DBA_ views?

If we don't see access to the DBA_ views, we drop down to the ALL_ views.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpKJmCoBy2c.
I suggest another approach for more convenience: You can drag and drop table from connection into relational screen to generate model and follow the step in the above tutorial for creating diagram.
Hope this help :)