# Query for All Tables and Fields in an Oracle Db

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using an Oracle DB with which I'm not familiar.

I would like to export something like a matrix of all tables *and fields*.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Export a diagram from a utiity?

<http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101819/1504882>

Comment: What do you say with **matrix**? Do you want a sql query or something else (diagram,etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use a system table `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`

```
SELECT table_name, column_name 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
```

[**More information**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2091.htm)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM all_tables;
SELECT * fROM all_tab_columns;
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sys_tables/