# How to export image of relational model in Oracle SQL Data Modeler?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have a relational model in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler with tables and relationships. Is it possible to export that relational model to a image file?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is possible, but looks like is not very intuitive.

1. Zoom your relational model to the expected resolution (at least to be readable).
2. Go to **File**, then **Data Modeler**, then **Print Diagram** and selected the desired format.

This will generate an image file with your relational model with the current zoom level as the resolution.

Comment: Current zoom level as resolution seems not to work with version 4.

Comment: Sounds so promising, but literally does nothing when I click it. Both image and PDF options appear to do nothing. Do the files get generated without user prompt in some specific location?

Comment: when picking a format I'm getting 'There is no printable area' =/

Comment: I was able to do this once, but now I try and happens the same as @juggernaut. "There is no printable area"

Answer (score 4):

Current path to printing model in SQL developer is:

```
File -> Data Modeler -> Print Diagram -> To ... File
```

Comment: does not function at all

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I did figure out how to make it work using a different thread on stack overflow.

[How to generate an entity-relationship (ER) diagram using Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580529/how-to-generate-an-entity-relationship-er-diagram-using-oracle-sql-developer)