# PLSQL, SQL*PLUS get current username?

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I know that the show user command return: USER is "SCOTT"

But is it possible in a sql query or in a plsql script to only get the username of the current user and store it in a variable?

Comment: `select user from dual`

Answer (score 11):

The `USER` built-in function may be used.

```
DECLARE
  v VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  v := USER;
END;
```

Comment: Notice this calls `STANDARD.USER()`, [which produces a PL/SQL to SQL context switch](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/09/07/beware-of-hidden-pl-sql-to-sql-context-switches/). Better use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23417565/521799) instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
SYS_CONTEXT( 'USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER' )
```

Comment: Deprecated as of 10g, better to use 'SESSION_USER' instead: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
fnd_profile.value('USERNAME')
fnd_profile.value('USER_ID')
fnd_flobal.user_id
```

these can be used to get the user details

Comment: `fnd_profile` is not a standard Oracle package. Can you give a link to the Oracle manual?

Comment: refer this for more info [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T457084.htm)

Comment: That's Oracle E-Business Suite. That is something different than Oracle's database product. You can't use those functions in SQL or PL/SQL through SQL\*Plus