# How to update an ER diagram in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-relationship

After I make an ER diagram according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580529/how-to-generate-an-entity-relationship-er-diagram-using-oracle-sql-developer), how would I update it when I make changes to the source data tables? If I retry the process that the referenced question mentions after changing the source data, I get an error box that prompts me to "merge" the tables (which I've found still doesn't reflect the updates I made to the source).