# How to get table relationships/structural diagram/Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) or dependencies in Oracle? database?

Tags: sql, oracle, erd

I am new to using Oracle database.I have been given an oracle database to learn. I need to know that how to find table relationships. I don't have oracle data modeler or don't know any safe third party tool. 
**Is it possible to generate such diagram or table relationship in any kind of representation with SQL/PL SQL queries?**

Comment: you can use oracle sql developer  data modeler, its free. just use a google

Comment: How to generate a diagramm you can read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580529/how-to-generate-an-entity-relationship-er-diagram-using-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: Asking an Oracle novice to navigate a physical data model without providing the necessary tools is sociopathic behaviour. Oracle Data Modeler is free, and supports reverse engineering. You can download it from [the Oracle site here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/datamodeler.html).